# Asynchronously loading images on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I have a grid of images that are loaded from the web, but there's a bit of lag/stutter while scrolling. I'm using an asynchronous `ASIHTTPRequest` to make the requests, so the download itself is happening in a separate thread, but because UIKit isn't thread-safe, once I receive the `NSData` response, I have to call `UIImage initWithData` on the main thread.

Profiling shows that, by far, the bottleneck consists of the internal PNG parsing functions invoked by `UIImage initWithData`. I'm interested in doing this in a background thread, so the main UI remains responsive and there's less lag.

But I'm not sure exactly how to do this. It sounds like the right direction is to use `CGImageRef`, since Core Graphics is thread-safe, but I only see `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider` and `CGImageCreateWithJPEGGDataProvider`, whereas `UIImage initWithData` supports a large list of image types.

I want something that has the same functionality as `UIImage initWithData` but doesn't have the thread-safety issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `UIImage` `initWithData` in a background thread safely. As a good rule of thumb, what you can't do in a background thread is alter user interface elements. In this case, you should not be setting the `image` property of a `UIImageView`, or adding a `UIImageView` to a superview in a background thread.

However, creating a `UIImage` instance is safe, and will work with no problems.

Comment: I don't know if it's in the docs, to be honest. I never run into an issue with it, though.